# JavaScript page transition issue with WordPress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'd like to add a fade in/fade out page transition when a visitor clicks on Create an Account using JavaScript. Using the code below, the fade out transition works just fine. The issue is with the registration page not loading correctly. When the registration page loads, its all white. If I refresh the page, the content appears but it should be fading in as the page loads.

I think the issue is with ajax possibility. Not sure that I'm suppose to be using .php on Line 13 and 14.

```
const newPage = $(data).filter("body").php()            
$("body").php(newPage)
```

I'm using WordPress but I'm not sure if that matters.

```
$("a.create-account").on("click", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault()

    const href= $(this).attr("href")

    window.history.pushState(null, null, href)

    $.ajax({    
        url:href,   
        success: function (data) {
            $("body").fadeOut(250, function() {         
                const newPage = $(data).filter("body").php()            
                $("body").php(newPage)          
                $("body").fadeIn(250)               
            })  
        }   
    })  
})
```

In the end, I would just like to fade out the homepage and fade in the registration page. I think I'm about half way there. Just need a little help getting to the finish line.

Comment: What's `$("body").php(newPage)`? jQuery has no `.php()` function

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Unless you're using a library that has a `.php()` JavaScript function, what you have now won't do anything.

Comment: Its me trying to convert the original code from .html to .php for the sake of WordPress. When I leave .html instead of changing it to .php, the fade out transition works, but the new page doesn't load. Its almost like it just refreshes the homepage. I think you're onto the correct location of the failure.

Comment: https://www.superhi.com/video/simple-page-transitions-with-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: I removed $("body").php(newPage) and this site is functioning in the same manner. This line wasn't needed. Thx. Its still loading a blank white page instead of loading the content from the registration page.